# jQuery's `on` doesn't see children elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to have an event listener on my main div (`.main`). I want to detect clicks on `article`'s children `header`. My code attempts are as follow:

```
var area = $('article.small-post').children('.inner').children('header');
```

```
var area = $('article.small-post > .inner > header');
```

```
var area = 'article.small-post > .inner > header';
```

```
$('.main').on('click', area, function() {
     alert('bam');
});
```

None of the `area` code works. Only when I put single `article.small-post`, code fires. Where's my mistake?

HTML:

```
<div class="main">
<article class="small-post">
    <div class="inner">
        <header>
            title
        </header>
        <div class="entry">
            entry
        </div>
        <footer class="footer"></footer>
    </div>
</article>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show html code?

Comment: Only `area3` has a chance of working. If it doesn't, you selector is wrong. Show us your HTML.

Comment: I've updated the question with html (I've cut out texts).

Comment: The second argument to .on must be a selector, not a jQuery object.

Comment: `article` doesnt have the class `.small-post`...

Comment: There is no class `main` above?

Comment: There is. I've updated the code.

Comment: The "area3" version should work fine.

Comment: @TomekBuszewski Is this snippet waiting for the DOM to be ready?

Comment: @Karl - yes, it's inside `$(document).ready`.

Comment: @Pointy - well, it's not ;-)

Comment: you have an extra `}` in your code throwing an error `;}});`

Comment: @scrappedcola yes, I've found it prettyfiying the JS. Hope it's a typo...

Comment: @scrappedcola - it's a typo (but it's my kind of mistake ;-))

Comment: i do those too so it's my first check :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, only `area3` will work because `.on` second parameter accept a string.

Then, you have an extra bracket :

```
$('.main').on('click', area#, function() {alert('bam');}});
                                                        ^-here
```

Remove it and it work

```
$('.main').on('click', area3, function() {alert('bam');});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ondd6nw7/

Comment: That's actually a typo, I don't have it in my code. But then again, your code works great on the fiddle, I wonder why mine doesn't.

Comment: @Regent the original code. OP meant that he tried `area1`, `area2` and `area3`

Comment: @TomekBuszewski Well, any error? Can you show the full code?

Comment: No, no, my mistake, code works ;-) Thank you very much!

Comment: @TomekBuszewski What was it finally? The typo?

Comment: Funny thing, it should be working from the very beginning. Previously I targeted the whole `article` element, so inside the function, I used `$(this)` ;-) Now I changed it to `$(this).closest('article')` and it works great. Thanks alot once again, if it wasnt't for your fiddle, I would never found this ;-) Well, 13 hours of coding, kinda too much for today.

Comment: Your second snippet has the same typo as the first snippet. Did I miss something...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this helps you. Of course you can put `$main` directly inline.

```
var $main = $(".main");

$main.on("click", "header", function() {
    alert("header clicked");
});
```

> [See my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rgecsLuk/)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
$('.main article header').on('click', function() {
    // some code...
});
```

or try this:

```
$('.main article').on('click', 'header', function() {
    // some code...
});
```

You can find the difference explained [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events).

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I already solved the mistery ;-) Also, I work on delegated elements, so I can't target the `article`, I need its parent ;-)

Comment: Since articles are added dynamically the event can't be hooked at that level. But thanks for the interesting hint concerning performance for the variants!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do it like this?

```
$('.main article header').click(function(){
  alert('bam');
});
```

This was the alert will be triggered on all header elements that are in an article tag inside the main class.

Comment: Maybe because he want delegated event? Working on dynamic elements?

Comment: I use infinite scroll and your code woudn't trigger on new elements.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use Event Delegation to have all child clicks detected from one parent element.

An example would look like this:

`$('.my-parent-class').on('click','.my-inner-element',doSomething);`

More info here: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, this might solve your problem.

See the JSfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/90xn59ot/3/

JS code:

```
// Little modifications
var area = $('article').children('div.inner').children('header'),
area2 = $('article > .inner > header'),
area3 = 'article > .inner > header';

// Basically with the single element
// If you have more than one element
// -> simply loop over them...
// 
// @example
// 
// for(var i = 0; i < area.length; i++) {
//    $('div.main').on('click', area[i].tagName, function () {
//         #code goes here...
//    } 
// }

$('div.main').on('click', area[0].tagName, function () {
   alert('Activate me only');
   area[0].style.backgroundColor = getRandomColor();
   area[0].style.color = getRandomColor();
});

// This one is just for fun...
function getRandomColor() {
   var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
   var color = '#';
   for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
   color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
}
   return color;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
    var $main = $('.main');

    $main.on('click', function(e){
        var $target = $(e.target),
            $header = $('header');

        if($target.is($header)){
            //do something
        }
    });
});
```

By clicking on `.main`, you're sending a click event argument to the function which catches the click `target`. If that target is before declared `$main`, do something.

Comment: A brief explanation would be great.

Comment: By clicking on `.main`, you're sending a click event argument to the function which catches the click `target`. If that target is before declared `$main`, do something.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with my code, nor my answer, except people downvoted it because they needed an explanation for 3 lines of code.

Comment: I look at SO as not a help center, but a learning center. Your code is simple to you, but may not e for other people, especially less experienced.

Comment: That's all great, and you should look it that way, but you should first mind your own manners in downvoting people's answers before they even get a chance to modify **RIGHT** answers.

Comment: @Davion I didn't downvote nor do I have a dog in this fight. For future learning though, it's better to edit the original answer with the explanation vs. to add the explanation in a comment. I added it to your answer for you. Notice the difference it makes with the explanation in the answer. You have a well rounded answer now. :)

Comment: @Davion well, even though you overcomplicate the code by using `$(e.target)` and `$('header')` instead of delegated event, it works correctly, yes.

Comment: @Regent It's called `code **REUSABILITY**`, just because you don't get it, it doesn't mean it's complicated.

Comment: @Davion I understand how your code works, don't worry about me. The problem is that `$main.on('click', 'header', function() { //do something });` is much shorter and works slightly faster.

Comment: @Regent I agree with that, and you can only use it for checking the click for `header` element, nothing more.

Comment: @Davion that is what OP wanted. If some day in future he will want to add event handler to another elements in `main`, he will do it. There is no need to complicate and slow down code for the reason of "it might be used in future". Furthermore, if OP will want to add additional handler for `.entry`, it can be done by `$('.main').on('click', '.entry', function() { ... });` and in most cases it will work not worse (or maybe even still better) than `if-else` of `$(event.target)`. Let's just stop at this point. I voted up for your answer, as it is correct one, but I said what I have in my mind.